# How can I adjust the bar values placement in bar chart in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want to move the bar values in bar chart so that they are not merged into each other. My code is given below.

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
freq = [0.93, 0.87,0.86,0.87,0.93,0.84,0.74,0.79,0.78,0.95,0.88,0.8, 0.71]

width = 0.1 # width of the bars
xticklabels = ['NR-AHR','NR-AR','NR-AR-LBD','NR-Aromatase','NR-ER','NR-ER-LBD','NR-PPARG','SR-ARE','SR-HSE','SR-MMP','SR-P53','SR-ATAD5','AM']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x, freq, width, color='b')
#xlabels=['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8', 'X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12', 'X13']
ax.set_ylim(0.6,1)
ax.set_ylabel('auc-roc', fontsize=13)
#xlabels, rotation=45, rotation_mode="anchor"
ax.set_xticks(np.add(x,(width/2.2))) # set the position of the x ticks
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels,rotation = 75, ha="right")
#ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=45)
def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/1., 1*height,
                '%.2f' %(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)


rects1[0].set_color('r')
rects1[1].set_color('r')
rects1[2].set_color('r')
rects1[3].set_color('r')
rects1[4].set_color('r')
rects1[5].set_color('r')
rects1[6].set_color('r')
rects1[7].set_color('g')
rects1[8].set_color('g')
rects1[9].set_color('g')
rects1[10].set_color('g')
rects1[11].set_color('g')
rects1[12].set_color('b')
#fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(3.31, 3.5)
plt.savefig('Figure1.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The result of this code is given below.

[image: bar values are merged.]

What I want in my image is something like given below, where I can displace the bar values in such a way that they are nor merged and clearly visible.

Note: it should be noted that I want my image width to be the same.

[image: my desired ouput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you *don't want to increase the figure size*, here is a manual cheap hack to get what you want. I am just pasting the code modified. Rest everything stays the same as your code. I also shortened you `set_color` part at the end.  P.S: The width of the bars looks different because of some visualization/saving the figure. On my screen, they all look same width.

```
def autolabel(rects):
    for i, rect in enumerate(rects):
        height = rect.get_height()
        if i == 2 or i ==7:
            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/1., 1.07*height,
                '%.2f' %(height), ha='center', va='bottom')
            ax.vlines(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/3., 1.005*height, 1.07*height, lw=1, color='gray')
        else:    
            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/1., 1.01*height,
                '%.2f' %(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)

c = 7*['r'] + 5*['g'] + ['b'] 
for i, r in enumerate(rects1):
    r.set_color(c[i])
```

**Output**

[image]